# Opening Word document

Tags: cognito-forms

I have uploaded a Word .docx document but when I open it I cannot save it elsewhere or do a copy and paste of content.

How can I edit/work with the .docx file that I have uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

Steve,

I work with the Cognito Forms development team.

Currently to view an uploaded docx document or any Microsoft Office Type documents we are launching the file in the free Office Online Viewers.

A docx type document should open up in Word Online.
**Within Word Online there should be options to download the document or the option to save-as.**

*When you are viewing the document do you have the option to "Download" or does the document not open up in Word Online at all?*

I know we are talking about how to offer better options with access to attachments as people have requested to be able to export uploaded attachments but for the moment with MS Office documents the action is to open it with Office Online.

Comment: If you are not seeing the Word Online logo with a File, Download, Print, Find menu items below when viewing an uploaded document you might try clearing your browser cache or trying an alternative browser.  I helped someone out with something similar where the Word Online toolbar did not display in Chrome, but upon clearing the browser cache the Word Online viewer started working.